# Loading data for controller in Angular.js with resolve and $resource

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to load a job by Id from the API and pass it to the controller.

```
.when('/jobs/edit/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/jobs/edit',
    controller: 'JobCtrl',
    resolve: function($routeParams, Job){
        var jobId = $routeParams.id;

        return {
            job: function(){
                return Job.get({ id: jobId});
            }
        };
    }
})
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('App')
  .controller('JobCtrl', function ($scope, Job, $location, $routeParams) {
        $scope.newJob = data.job; //does not work
        $scope.errors = {};

        $scope.save = function (form) {
                   //...
        };
    });
```

Model:

```
angular.module('App')
    .factory('Job', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/jobs/:id', {
            id: '@id'
        }, { //parameters default
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    });
```

How do I get the data in the controller? My `resolve` block in the route is not even being executed.

Edit: this page has lots of examples of different types of resolving:
http://phillippuleo.com/articles/angularjs-timing-multiple-resource-resolves-ngroute-and-ui-router

Comment: Is `data.job` a typo? I'm not sure where you're expecting that data variable to come from?

Comment: doesn't resolve return an object with key `job: { ... }` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you resolve implementation is incorrect.
You could try to change router like:

```
.when('/jobs/edit/:id', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/jobs/edit',
  controller: 'JobCtrl',
  resolve: {
    job: function (Job, $routeParams) {
      return Job.get({id: $routeParams.id});
    }
  }
})
```

And get resoled data in controller by including `Job` into dependencies:

```
angular.module('App')
  .controller('JobCtrl', function ($scope, job, $location, $routeParams) {
    // job is resolved here
    $scope.job = job;
    $scope.newJob = {};
    $scope.errors = {};

    $scope.save = function (form) {
               //...
    };
  });
```

**UPDATED**
If you want to use `JobCtrl` either for creating and editing, you can return `null` in resoled `job` for new-job-page. It means: There aren't any job yet, till you create one.

```
.when('/jobs/new', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/jobs/new',
  controller: 'JobCtrl',
  resolve: {
    job: function () {
      return null;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This doens't work, as the promise has not resolved yet once inside the controller.

Comment: `controller('JobCtrl', function ($scope, Job` - It has to be `job` if you want the resolved data.

Comment: @chovy I made a mistake, zeroflagL corrected it. You need to include resolved parameter into controller dependencies. Edited, you can try it out.

Comment: this works, but there is one caveat, i'm using this controller for both creating a new and editing a job. In the case of new job, there is no resolver, so injecting the 'job' then throws an error in the controller since its not defined.

Comment: @chovy. You can use `$q` to wrap the $resource execution. Check [this out](http://pastebin.com/5PXcxiVZ).